# what is stdin file in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I'm checking my angular project in Chrome with inspect. and I found there are some css style from 'myproject/stdin:377' . but I want to know  where the css style comes from. so where is the stdin file? or what it is, how can I found it?

Comment: I believe it is your main css file you created/pointed Angular to